# R get fields by regex (or just first characters)

Tags: r, field

This is a beginner question but I could not find an answer elsewhere.

I am working with R and I have a simple structure which I can query using $ to obtain some of the fields.
You can obtain the data I work with by doing this:

```
  library(caret)
  library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
  set.seed(3433)
  data(AlzheimerDisease)
  adData = data.frame(diagnosis,predictors)
  inTrain = createDataPartition(adData$diagnosis, p = 3/4)[[1]]
  training = adData[ inTrain,]
  testing = adData[-inTrain,]
```

Now I want to obtain all variables in `training` that start with `IL` so that I can use them as input for the `preProcess` method. Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?grep`, and `?regex`. For example,

```
mynames <- c("IL1","a","b","IL2")
mynames[grep("^IL", mynames)]
```

or simply

```
grep("^IL", mynames, value = T)
```

Comment: You don't need to put `grep` inside `mynames`, just do `grep("^IL", mynames, value = T)`